# PSKill can't kill remote process under Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, automation, powershell

I have a server running Windows 8 Pro, and a client also running Windows 8 Pro. When attempting to kill a remote process on the server from the client via PSKill, I always get- "Access is denied". How I can solve this? Filesharing service is on, remote registry also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found, that in Windows 8 you need to enable admin share in registry. [Here](http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2012/10/windows-8-enable-the-admin-share/) you can find additional instructions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you get the most recent version:  PsKill v1.14

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683.aspx

2. Extract the file.  Go into the file properties and "unblock" the file.
3. Run command shell as an Administrator.

Comment: Unfortunately, until you enable the $admin share, not even the latest v1.15 (at the time of writing this) can make it work. So kudos to @Vadim Smakhtin